# css clip path animation trigger on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm building an animated menu to appear on hover with a clip animation. than fade out on mouseout.

I'm having a problem figuring out how to apply hover, since the 'hovered' table is fully clipped at the start of the animation, and that cause the animation to restart if the mouse is moving on the table. Guess the problem is element the changes shape while mouse still hovering.

Here  is  how its looks like: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YrGzwE

```
table:hover {
    animation: load 0.45s ease-out;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I'm not really looking for full css solution but would like to avoid jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the hover state to the container:

```
#tableContainer:hover table {
    animation: load 0.45s ease-out;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXEVRv